# Using argparse to pass in number of output lines

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a program that outputs a list. Let's say this list can have hundreds of items. I want to use argparse to pass in an option for how many items are shown in the output, and default to 15 lines. How do I get the option to be passed through as a variable in my function?

```
def get_args(argv = None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
    # ...omitted code for other options
    parser.add_argument(
        '-n',
        '--noutput',
        default = 15,
        type = int,
        help = 'Number of lines in output'
    )
    return parser.parse_args(argv)


def scramble_words():
"""
Shuffle words in new_list
Print reordered words by newline
"""
    random.shuffle(new_list)
    print( )
    print("\n\n".join(new_list[:--noutput]))
```

Comment: What answer other than the obvious "pass the value to the function which needs it" do you expect?

Comment: More specifically, my question is how I would set a variable from my option. I was going through argparse doc and testing what I wrote, but am unable to add a variable within the parser.add_argument part. Will keep reading the doc to see if I can find the answer...

Comment: `get_args().noutput` contains the value. You're not showing how you are calling either of these functions so we can't tell exactly what you are going wrong. The `scramble_words` definition should obviously be changed to accept an argument (perhaps optional).

Comment: I see! Yup will add the argument to scramble_words and play with this. Thanks so much!

Comment: During debugging it's a good idea to print the result of `parse_args()`.  That will give you a clearer idea of what the parser has done.  It shows the names and values of the attributes it has parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) package for creating command line options. I personally find it more intuitive.

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-n', '--noutput')
def driver(noutput):
    print(noutput)

def scramble_words(noutput):
    """
    Shuffle words in new_list
    Print reordered words by newline
    """
    new_list=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    random.shuffle(new_list)
    print( )
    print("\n\n".join(new_list[:--noutput]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver()
```

If you want to stick with argparse, here is how you can pass the argument to your function. I made some assumption on how you might be using the code.

```
import sys
import argparse
import random

def get_args(argv = None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '-n',
        '--noutput',
        default = 15,
        type = int,
        help = 'Number of lines in output'
    )

    return parser.parse_args()

def scramble_words(noutput):
    """
    Shuffle words in new_list
    Print reordered words by newline
    """
    new_list=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    random.shuffle(new_list)
    print( )
    print("\n\n".join(new_list[:--noutput]))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    args = get_args(sys.argv)
    scramble_words(args.noutput)
```

Comment: `[:--noutput]` is that some new indexing syntax? :)  A special double negative?

Comment: Should probably be just `[:noutput]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help here! I was able to get it working from both your and @tripleee's inputs. Click package definitely seems more intuitive; I need to try optparse as well to get a better understanding here. Really appreciate it!!

Comment: I did initially use [:--noutput] and see it works here, as well as [:noutput]. Is it safe to say this is a best-practice sort of approach?

Comment: You probably put the `--` assuming the dashes were part of the variable's name. They are wrong and it just coincidentally happens to work anyway, probably because Python parses two consecutive minuses into effectively a redundant plus. "Best practice" to omit them is a gross understatement IMNSHO,

Comment: I wouldn't bother with `optparse`, it's basically just even clunkier and more hostile than `argparse`. The ostensible improvements in `argparse` are not in areas which affect beginners. I hesitantly condone `click` as a somewhat more user-friendly alternative, though there are several competing third-party libraries and a bit of a shakeout going on between them. Let's earnestly hope `click` or something like it comes out as a clear winner and ideally eventually a part of the *de facto* standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing how you are calling either of these functions, but something like

```
def scramble_words(lst, n=15):
    """
    Shuffle words in lst
    Print n reordered words by newline
    """
    random.shuffle(lst)
    print()
    print("\n\n".join(lst[:n]))

# ...
args = get_args()
scramble_words(new_list, args.noutput)
```

A better design would have the caller do the printing, and probably only print a single newline between words.

Comment: Ah, sorry for omitting the details there. Yup, I'm going to use scramble_words(new_list, args.noutput) here. And ha, thanks for the memo on the printing! Definitely felt silly printing a blank line at first...